# jquery ui sortable: How to get current index with id and old index with id and pass parameter in ajax in update event

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 html tables. I am using jquery UI to change the position of the table and pass this jquery event arguments through ajax while taking index and item id of the table position so that I can update in the database the current position of the table.Right now i am able to get the position of current index with id but i want to get the old index with their id as well. So that i can take both the old index,old id,new index,new id positions and store easily in database.But not sure how to do that.

Here is fiddle:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/22/)

Here is my code:

**dashboard.js**

```
$("#widget_update").sortable({      
      update : function(event, ui) {
          var widget = $('#widget_update').sortable('serialize');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'show-widget','widget':ui.item.index(),'item':ui.item[0].id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#widget').html(data.html);                           
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Error');         
        }
        });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/PP2ba/)**

JS code :

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    /*stop: function(event, ui) {
        alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }*/
    start: function(e, ui) {
        // creates a temporary attribute on the element with the old index
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
        // gets the new and old index then removes the temporary attribute
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        var oldIndex = $(this).attr('data-previndex');
        var element_id = ui.item.attr('id');
        alert('id of Item moved = '+element_id+' old position = '+oldIndex+' new position = '+newIndex);
        $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');

        ///code to pass the data using AJAX
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your_url",
        data: {'item_id':element_id,'item_old_index':oldIndex,'item_new_index':newIndex},
        success: function(data){
            //code on success
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Error');         
        }
        });
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

HTML code:

```
<h4>Notice: The actual index of the elements starts from 0</h4>
<ul id="sortable"> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li> 
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item_7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi rahul i ahve question how can i store it into the database now then ?

Comment: Hi user3702602 ! I have added the code to pass the data using AJAX in the `update: function(e, ui) {` block. See my updated answer. Hope you got everything right you wanted !

Comment: yes Rahul i can pass the value but how to retrieve it in my php file i have to use foreach statement i am trying this but not able to get it.It is saying invlaid argument pass to foreach:foreach ($_POST["item"] as $value) {
    // print_r($value);
    $id = $value["id"];
    $position = $value["position"];
}

Comment: Just put a `print_r($_POST)` on you PHP page and try to get the values using like `$item_id = $_POST['item_id']` and so on...

Comment: yes Rahul but i have many items and how can update their positions then if i just take $_POST....i have to use foreach statement right ?

Comment: I mean i have to assign old postion to the item position it replace and new postiion with the replaced item

Comment: Hi @Rahul how can i get the old element here ? i am getting current element now with its new,old position but i also want to get the old element name...

Comment: The old element is the element itself that is moved, and in the code you can get the id of the element that is moved

Comment: but if you think about many elements then how can we update their postion in the database ? so that we can get always the position set elements for users ?

Comment: I think what you need is to get the id of all the elements with their current positions and update all them in database, right ?

Comment: No its not the right way you may have 50 elements so you cant write 50 update statement for them...so thats why i am trying to do with foreach ()

Comment: Sorry buddy ! but for now I don't have answer for your problem !